# Can't get redis connector to work with g-wan

Tags: c, redis, g-wan

Did all the hiredis installation
defaulting to make make install etc

Result running g-wan:
Linking hellox.c: undefined symbol: redisConnect

online says linking lib is wrong? how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Read how to [link libraries with G-WAN](http://gwan.ch/faq#use_libraries). Even with GCC you need to tell the linker what library is in use. G-WAN is not different.

Comment: i've read multiple times. I can't seem to get hiredis working or to be linked? tried everything. tried for hours.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Linking hell.c: undefined symbol: redisConnectWithTimeout
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#include "gwan.h" // G-WAN exported functions
#pragma include "./libraries/hiredis"
#include <hiredis.h>


please help. can you provide a tutorial just for linking hiredis properly? I'm trying to get http://ssdb.io/ cpp working too...

Comment: Please provide dockerize image for gwan on this. Please. Thanks!

Comment: **Docker** is a packaging product. Nobody will work on that without a good reason to invest hours for learning how this third-party product is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here my script working on my server :

```
#include "gwan.h" // G-WAN API
#pragma link "hiredis"
#include "hiredis/hiredis.h"
typedef struct
{
  redisContext *rCont;
  redisReply *rReply;
} data_t;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  data_t **d = (data_t**)get_env(argv, US_SERVER_DATA);
  xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
  u64 start = getus();
  const char *hostname = "127.0.0.1";
  int port = 6379;
  struct timeval timeout = { 1, 500000 }; // 1.5 seconds
  if(!d[0]) // first time: persistent pointer is uninitialized
  {
    d[0] = (data_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(data_t));
    if(!d[0])
        return 500; // out of memory
    d[0]->rCont  = redisConnectWithTimeout(hostname, port, timeout);
  }

  d[0]->rReply = redisCommand(d[0]->rCont,"PING");
  xbuf_xcat(get_reply(argv), "PING %s<br>", d[0]->rReply->str);
  freeReplyObject(d[0]->rReply);
  xbuf_xcat(get_reply(argv), "<hr>%llu µs<hr>", getus() - start);

  return 200;
}
```

You have to get hiredis compiled and copied into your lib directory.